# WebApi Support Implict Flow (with roles) and Client Credential Grant

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have a situation I haven't run into yet and wondering if I need to write a custom authorize attribute to handle this situation or if there is something in the identity framework I should be using.

I need to support both Implicit flow (mostly for swaggerUI integration) and client credential grant in my webapi.  The data I'm working with is sensitive and therefore I don't want anyone who discovers my swagger page and can authenticate with my AAD instance (through an implicit flow) to be able to consume my data.  I want to restrict the my api to look for roles in the jwt **IF THEY ARE PRESENT**.

On the flip side my WebApi is most likely going to be consumed by other services.  So I need to support client credential flow.  Obviously the tokens issued through the client credentials grant will not have a role claim, so I can't look for roles when I authorize these requests.

I'm basically looking for something like this:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "swagger_admin", Optional=true)]
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
```

But I'm not seeing something logically equivalant, and before I go out and write a custom authorize attribute I want to know what others have done here.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to validate if a) the token has a "roles" claim with the correct application permissions (client credentials grant) or b) the token has one of the allowed delegated permissions in the scp claim (+ a roles claim is present that says the user has a role that allows them to do this). You can refer to my article how to set them up in AAD: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad.

Comment: I also have a dual part article on doing this kind of thing in ASP.NET Core: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-1 & https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-2.

Comment: @juunas Ok so I need to create a custom authorize attribute that looks for the roles claim and when it's present looks for the specified roles.  Otherwise validates the audience in the claim (in the case of CC grant).  Did I interpret that right?

Comment: @cobolstinks I see juunas already gave some good suggestions.. although I want to add one key point, which I think is not clear as per your question.. My understanding is that you can actually assign app roles to other applications as well.. your role definition in manifest needs to allow it.. then you will be able to assign roles to other applications (portal UI steps are a little different than what you do for users..).. I am highlighting this because you mention in your question "Obviously the tokens issued through the client credentials grant will not have a role claim"

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#approle-type In your app manifest, approle will need to mention `"allowedMemberTypes": ["User","Application"]` where it might be having only User today.. once you change manifest, you should be able to assign this role to other applications by going to their settings > required permissions > select an api (find your application where you defined roles).. select the roles in app permissions.. and then do admin consent using "grant permissions" button if both apps are in same tenant..

Comment: appRole with allowedMemberTypes containing Application == Application permission :) In client credentials case, you check "roles" claim for valid app permission. In other cases, you check "scp" claim for valid delegated permissions (+ optionally "roles" claim for valid user roles if you have those).

Comment: Also, defining appRoles that allow both users and apps isn't something I'd do commonly. Usually user's roles are different from app permissions.

Comment: Thanks both of you, you have given me some more things to investigate.  It sounds like I'm going to want to assign my CC grant clients an application role and check for that in the Authorize attribute as well as the user role from implicit grant clients and I should be good.  I'll play around and report back with my findings, didn't know there were application roles allowed, pretty neat thing.